# Is there any well-known result about differentiability of the limit of a sequence of diff. functions?

Tags: real-analysis

I am thinking if I have a sequence of functions $f_n$ for which each of these functions is differentiable and that converges to a function $f$ in some norm (let's say the $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ norm for continous functions).

Without some assumptions, I know $f$ must not be necessarily differentiable (for example, any continuous function can be approximated by step functions), but what extra assumptions do I need for it?

Also, what if $f_n$ is differentiable almost everywhere? what should I add in my hypothesis to assure that $f$ is differentiable a.e.?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't even ensure differentiability for $f_n \in C_c^\infty$ (compactly supported)...

Comment: Some of what's in this [29 December 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5461518) may be of interest, but overall it's probably more technical than what you're looking for.

Comment: yay sci.math! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who didn't click the link in the comments, the short answer is: if $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ uniformly and $(f'_n)$ converges to $g$ uniformly then $f$ is differentiable and $g=f'$.